# How to enable Typescript features again after 1.0RC upgrade?

Tags: typescript

Typescript 1.0RC is totally unusable in VS 2012.
If the solution is to upgrade to VS 2013, that's fine.
But what if I am unable to upgrade to VS 2013 - is Typescript officially supported for VS 2012?

After upgrading to the RC im facing the following issues:
- Can't place breakpoints in Typescript files ("this is not a valid place for a breakpoint").
- Double-clicking on a typescript word in the editor takes much longer to highlight (at worst case it takes a matter of seconds).
- There is frequent freezing of the VS editor (worst case it takes a matter of seconds).
- F12 (go to definition) no longer works.

I'm sure there are more issues.
What can i do to resolve these issues?
I have VS 2012 with Web Essentials (which exposes Typescript as an option).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done a repair install of TypeScript?

Comment: hmm. thanks. this seemed to have fixed the F12, but still everything is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the debbuging of typescript:

It seems that the typescript compiler does not generate sourcemaps (.js.map) by default since I installed the RC1 visual studio plugin in VS2012. The option -sourcemap is probably not set by default. (If sourcemaps are created, the debugger is able to map the generated javascript on to the typescript file).

But I cannot find an option in VS2012 to enable this. Does somebody know how? Or do we have to wait on an Visual Studio update?

A possible (temporary, I hope) workaround:
Compile the .ts file you want to debug using the command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.9> tsc -sourcemap someTypescriptFile.ts
```

This will generate the .js file, but also a .js.map file.